# eleventy & pug: Create blog list by looping over pug blog posts

Tags: pug, eleventy

I have a list of blog posts written in the pug template language. Each blog post has a frontmatter header. For example:

```
---
id: "achilles-turtle-metapost"
title: "The achilles & turtle metapost"
date: "2019-08-14"
img: "blue-liquid.png"
tags: ["Achilles & Turtle", "Philosophy"]
excerpt: "Who is this achilles and his calm friend the turtle? And what are they talking about every day?"
---
p Some very simple content of this blog post.
p Dummy second paragraph
```

The templates are parsed with the static site generator [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev)

The blog-list.pug looks like this. The variable `collections.all` is correctly filled with data about my blog posts by Eleventy.

```
- for (var postIdx = 0; postIdx < collections.all.length; postIdx++)
  include blog-list-item.pug
```

My problem: The blog-list-item.pug needs the **data of the current element in the for loop.** How can I access that inside the blog-list-item.pug partial?

I already tried this, but does not work. (This works in plain pug):

```
- for (var postIdx = 0; postIdx < collections.all.length; postIdx++)
  - var post = collections.all[postIdx].data   // this is a reference to the frontmatter data
  include blog-list-item.pug
```

The `post` variable is available inside `blog-list-item.pug` when using plain pug. The JavaScript context is passed to included templates by pug. But not when doing all that with Eleventy.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to access the data items in the `collections.all` array instead of just looping through the indexes.

eg:

```js
- for (const post of collections.all)
  include blog-list-item.pug
```

---

Then, depending on how you've set up the partials, you may be able to just access those variables with the include - if having trouble maybe see hints [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1692#issuecomment-59903526)).

Alternatively, you can pug's [`mixins`](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) instead of partials to pass in the variable as a parameter:

```
   +blog-list-item(post)
```